What tool do I need to take this nut off?
Car is a Honda civic coupe vti 2000.
As you can see in the pictures if you want to take the battery clamps off you need to loosen or remove the nuts.  However the nut is so close to the round casing(sorry I don’t know how to describe these) that if you use a standard ratchet there is not enough clearance for it to fit properly.  You end up hooking it at an angle and it doesn’t get tight enough.
Likewise I used a spanner and although there is the spanner points still don’t get enough clearance.  I used the reverse end of the spanner which is a circle and not very thick so this was the best but still wasn’t fitting and was at an angle.
In the end I just hand tightened it and then use the circle end of the spanner at an angle to  tighten it a bit more.  But it all feels every unprofessional.

does using the ratchet/spanner end at an angle damage the nut or tools, I’d imagine yes because it feels like you are stripping the metal as it’s not fitting properly.

what tool should I be using for this exactly since a standard ratchet or spanner go in at an angle and do not get enough clearance to comfortably tighten the nuts?


Thanks.



First thing you need to do before you tighten anything up is to clean the terminals. Corrosion breeds corrosion. You need to get ALL of the green stuff off of the positive side. Make it spic-n-span clean. Then worry about how to get the fastener tightened.

Paulster2 good comment.  This has now fixed some other issues I was having.

As a relative novice under the hood, you may not be aware of the technique of using an open-end wrench (spanner) to turn a nut just 1/12 of a turn at a time, then flipping the wrench over to access the same flats on the nut for another 1/12 of a turn.
Battery connectors are the one place I have to do this most often.
The flats on an open end wrench are oriented at an angle with the long axis of the wrench, so this allows you to turn a nut or bolt head bit by bit by repeatedly flipping the wrench. It's tedious, but sometimes it's the only way to turn a fastener in tight quarters.

You can do one of three things.
First, you could get a boxed end offset spanner which looks something like this:

Better yet, find them with deeper sockets. The thing about these are they have a thinner wall at the tip to allow it to get access to the nuts like what you've got.
Another thing you can do is to get better clamps for the battery which won't bend back over on themselves, blocking your ability to get to the nut in the first place.
The third thing you can do is bend the tip of the clamp back to its original position, which would expose the nut more. Over time as the clamp has been removed/replaced, it has slightly bent to the right (as you look down on it) causing the nut to become cramped against the side. By bending the part back into position, you're getting it back to where it should be and giving you access.

How can I bend it back to original? Do you mean pliers.  I’m Not quite sure how I would manage this thought if it’s originally like that restoring it is best.  Thanks.

@JamesWilson - If a pair of pliers is what you have, then yes. I'll guarantee you it was not like what it is now new. It will not take much of a tweak to expose the nut more so you can get a wrench on it.

You're not alone as many battery cable connections use the same @#)(!#*&^# fasteners. Try using a battery wrench made for this or small to medium size adjustable wrench to grab at least two flat spots on the nut to loosen them. A drop of motor oil can help lube the corroded threads, working the nut cw and ccw to help oil seep into threads. For dried battery acid, bluish-white deposits, a warm water solution of baking soda is all you need with a toothbrush to dissolve and neutralize acid. Immediate bubbling is the reaction between acid and baking soda in water. Plain water rinse, Auto stores sells battery cleaner in a spray can....with a combination grease, baking soda and solvents. Once cleaned up, add washers of appropriate size to move the nut away from the clamps. Grease after reassembling.
